# Dropped the default postgres database in Postgresql server

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recovery

I did not know what the database did and I deleted it without realizing that now I wouldn't be able to run psql again. How do I get thngs back to normal again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postgres` database isn't really needed.

But you can re-create it using:

```
psql -U postgres -d template1
psql (13.1)

postgres=# create database postgres;
```

The `-d template1` tells `psql` to connect to the template1 database.

Comment: that worked, thanks! I was afraid that postgres was the only way in..